# Analytic solution of a compact operator eigenvector (integral equation)

Tags: operator-theory, fredholm-operators

In [Sewall Wright's Evolution of Mendalian Population](https://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/16/2/97.full.pdf), the equation for the nonrecurrent mutation is
$$\frac{\phi(x)}n = \binom n {nx}\int_0^1 q^{nx}(1-q)^{n(1-x)}\phi(q)\,dq,\quad \forall x\in[0,1],$$
where $n>0$ and $\binom a b$ is the binomial coefficient. We are to solve for a nonzero function $\phi\ne0$. It is an eigenvalue problem of a compact operator (Fredholm equation of the second kind). But what is a general method for solving this integral equation? dirichlet  Is there a transform, say Mellin transform, that does the trick?